# "Escape" key event propagation

Tags: monaco-editor

I have hosted Monaco editor in a panel which can be close using "Escape" key. Now if **Find widget** is open in the editor pressing "Escape" should only close the widget but currently it closes panel as well. Any idea how we can handle this so that only Find widget closes not the panel?

Comment: Any idea why i got down vote for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This got answered here https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1017. Basically monaco editor give flexibility to add commands

```
editor.addCommand(monaco.KeyCode.Escape, function() {
    alert('I should close my panel!');

}, '!findWidgetVisible && !inReferenceSearchEditor && !editorHasSelection')
```